# Reset REDIS db through CLI?

Tags: redis, command-line-interface

I am in the process of adding REDIS as a distributed cache to my application. When I run automated integration tests, I would like have each test start with a clean instance - so, create the DB if it does not exist, or clear it if it does.

When I do this for my Oracle instance, I just drop the configured user and recreate it, resulting in a clean slate. What would the REDIS equivalent be? The only way I have found to create DBs is to use the Web UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *believe* you can do this, but (for obvious reasons) I have no intention to try it!

```
redis-cli flushall
```

Documentation [here](https://redis.io/commands/flushall).